# Rewrite to https causing apache recursion error with junk url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following code on my website in .htaccess to rewrite all requests to .https

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This generally works just fine. Now for the problem. If I submit a junk url, say domain.com/../../../../etc/psswd, modsecurity does its thing and issues a 403 error code. Also in the same .htaccess I have several ErrorDocument directives, including one for 403. The issue though is that, particularly when I use an iPad or iPhone but my laptop will do it too sometimes, the browser will display (for the above junk url), a 403 error and an additional statement that there was a 500 error while trying to use an ErrorDocument.

The apache error_log provides the following error:  'Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.'

If I comment out the above two RewriteRules in .htaccess the problem goes away, but then I am not redirecting to https. The frustrating bit is that this does not seem to happen all the time. I believe this is happening because my two rewrites to https are catching these junk urls in a recursion loop, I am just at a loss as to how to fix it and maintain my rewrites to https.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have both of your rules like this with an additional condition:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

And make sure these rules are right on top before all other rules.

New condition `%{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$` will skip these 2 rules after `ErrorDocument` directive has triggered.

Comment: Thanks for this. It sort've works, but is causing an interesting problem. If I put the url as https + junk url it all works fine. But if I put the url as http + junk url the error page comes up but there is no styling or images but the source shows the links are correct. And links, even though they seem to point at the correct target, are not working.

Comment: Ok now you've hit the most common problem people face when switching to pretty URL schemes :P Solution is also simple, just use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Comment: That's the thing, I have the slash for the root directory. Network log in IE Developer Tools shows all requests for css, images and js being aborted. Only happens when I use http in the url. If I use https it works fine.

Comment: what URLs do you see in your network log for css, js and what is the correct URL example?

Comment: The urls are correct, same as if I use https. What is interesting is that the file type is different, if I use https the type is text/css for a css file, or text/javascript for a js file. But if I use http the types shown are all text/html.

Comment: well in that case there is something else since rewrite rules aren't changing MIME type at all. If you have more code in your .htaccess please post in your question. (Though I believe this answer already worked for you to resolve the stated problem of infinite looping)

Comment: Yeah, I am going to select your answer as correct. Just troubleshooting why this is happening. If I use RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 403^$ before the RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off, it all seems to work. Just trying to figure out why.

Comment: Yes that will also work but remember that will work for 403 status only. If in case 404 is generated than it won't work.

Comment: Nah, didnt work. It worked for 403, but not for anything else, even normal rewrites when everything was fine werent working. This is frustrating because it does not behave consistently between my laptop, iphone, and ipad. Could caching be causing this consistency problem? As I said, I am selecting your answer because you answered the question as posed.

Comment: Oh sorry about that. Yes `R=301` does cause caching in browsers. It is better to use `R=302` while testing rules.